# Does 200 mean download is complete?

Tags: php, http, download, zip, response

I want verify that the download of a 300 MB zip file is complete. Will I get a 200 response before the download is complete? If not, here is a PHP function that might meet my needs.

```
<?php

function downloadComplete() {

  while (http_response_code() != 200) {
    set_time_limit(30);
    sleep(60 * 10); 
  }

  return true;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You could http_reponse_code manually. It does not mean that download is complete.

Also, only client side could "say" that file was downloaded. Server side could "say" that file was sent.